# Is it possible to define visual style from code rather then from xaml?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I would like to create (extend core button class probably) basic button programmatically on request and add it to a main canvas when ready. Is it possible to set a styling from the code (it is going to be width/height and transparent background, nothing else), rather then having visual styles in xaml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is just another class.

```
Style buttonStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.WidthProperty, 100));
buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.HeightProperty, 75));
buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, new SolidBrush(...)));

myButton.Style = buttonStyle;
```

Comment: And that will suffice? No need to have a xaml file anywhere?

Comment: Correct, in fact, you can do Silverlight without any XAML. XAML is just a way of specifying the state of objects.

Comment: But can I set the style for the button from the constructor of that button, like: this.Style = buttonStyle?

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you create your own Button class.